# How to add class to to angular application using angular-cli command: 'ng generate class' without receiving error

Tags: angular-cli

I'm referenceing https://www.sitepoint.com/ultimate-angular-cli-reference/, which says, `To add a class called 'UserProfile', run`:

`$ ng generate class user-profile`

When I run this command, I get

```
installing class  
Unable to find any apps in `angular-cli.json`
```

Comment: what is your cli version ? I am on `1.3.1` Just did `ng new my-app` then `ng generate class user-profile` and all just working fine. Are you sure that you are funning the command inside your cli project?

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this source code](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/%40angular/cli/utilities/app-utils.ts#L10) you got that error because your `.angular-cli.json` does not containg `apps` field. Just generate a new `sample-app` and compare its`.angular-cli.json` with your one.

Comment: I was starting out with the Angular Quickstart seed: angular.io/guide/setup, and the command was not working with the image of files that you get from cloning the github repo <br/>
   
Anyways the command worked if i create the project using the 'ng new' command.<br/>

Neither projects, the quick start one, or the ng new one contain '.angular-cli.json' . They both contain 'angular-cli.json' and the files are identical

<br/>
cli:1.3.0